# Youtube video visit count will increase if we open using a youtubeplayer library in android app

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Suppose we will watch video in YouTube using webbrowser in laptop/ mobile, then the views(visit) count will add for that video. But Will open a same youtube video using youtubeandroidplayer library in android app, so will that video views count will add to that video using a library?

Comment: Why not just take the sample app and test it ?

Answer (score 0):

**Question** >> so will that video views count will add to that video using a library?

**Answer :- No** it won't.